# Determining the closure of a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have the metric space ($\mathbb R^2, d_{\infty}$).

Let $A_0=[0,1]\times {0}$ and for every $n\geq 1$ define $A_n=[(\frac{1}{n},0),(\frac{1}{n},1)]$.

Then define the set $\displaystyle A= \bigcup_{n \geq 0} A_n$ .

Show that the closure of $A$, $\overline{A} = A \cup [(0,0),(0,1)]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you wanted $A = ]0,1[ \times \{0\}$, so that $(0,1) \notin A_0$.

First note that $A \cup \{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ is closed: it's equal to $K \times [0,1]$, where $K = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}: n \ge 1 \}$. So $A$ is even compact (in the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but this is equivalent to $d_{\infty}$.

Of course the closure of $A$ has to contain all points of $A$, and so you only need to see that $(0,0) \in \overline{A}$, which is clear as $({1 \over n},0) \rightarrow (0,0)$ and all the points in the sequence are in their respective $A_n \subset A$. Similarly, $(0,1)$ is a  limit of points from $A$, so in $\overline{A}$.

Comment: thank you for your discusssion,now (0,0) and (0,1) are in the cloure of A ,but how can I show that the whole segment joining (0,0) and (0,1) is in the closure of A? I proved that A \cup the segment [(0,0),(0,1)] lies in the closure of A using a similar discussion as yours,now if I can prove that the closure of A lies in A\cup the segment [(0,0),(0,1)] I get the equality.I know that a point is in the closure if there is a sequence in A tending to this point.A sequence in A is either in A0 or in An for some n, but there are many cases for such sequences, can you help from here?

Comment: The other points of the segment are in $A_0$. If $B$ is closed and we have $A \subset B$, then $\overline{A} \subset \overline{B} = B$, so the closure is at most the closed set $B$, and the closure lies between $A$ and $B$. In this case the difference is just two points, and the sequences show that they are indeed part of the closure.